# Power law degree distribution in R

Tags: r, power-law

For a given number of nodes, I need to generate a network with p(p − 1)/10 edges and a power law degree distribution with an expected power parameter of 2, which should mimic real-world networks in R.

Input: I have my node count as 400 and number of edges as stated above is (400*399)/10.

Output: 400*400 matrix with edges in the cell as fitted according to power law.

Can you guys please help me to understand how can I fit this to a power law distribution?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?